# Process.GetProcessById enabling "debug mode"

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process

In one of my C# application (.NET 2) I use an unmanaged-mode library (C) that invokes some `OpenProcess()`s. I have recently added some C# code where `Process.GetProcessById()` is used. After this change, the `OpenProcess()`'s started succeeding even if applied to PIDs that were used to make them fail. After some investigation, I discovered that `Process.GetProcessById()` implicitly sets `SeDebugPrivilege` to the application (NOTE: the current user has administrator's privilege). Since in my particular application this behavior is not desirable, I eventually restored the normal privileges by invoking `Process.LeavDebugMode()`.

Since I can't find any description of this, I have some concerns about the correctness of my program. Is it correct to call `Process.LeavDebugMode()` to "adjust" the `Process.GetProcessById()`'s job? And, in short, does my `Process.GetProcessById()`'s work as expected (e.g. documented by MSDN) or does the behavior I observed hide some subtle bug in my application?

My OS is Windows 7 SP1 64 bits for embedded systems.

EDIT: more info: the process runs in 32-bit mode (i.e. it runs the 32-bit version of .NET engine). Also, I have added this ".config" file to ensure that the .NET version in use is 2:

```
<configuration>
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

EDIT2: More experiments: Written a plain C#/WindowsForm application (thanks to MS wizard ;-) ), added two buttons, one to invoke `Process.GetProcessById()` and one to invoke `Process.LeaveDebugMode()`. Here's the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace testproc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.LeaveDebugMode();
        }
    }
}
```

Launched the application (outside VS), then I launched process explorer. It confirmed the weird "feature":

- Application just started up: SeDebugPrivilege disabled
- Button 1 pressed: **SeDebugPrivilege enabled!**
- Button 2 pressed: SeDebugPrivilege disabled again
- Button 1 pressed: SeDebugPrivilege still disabled (uhm...)

So, I can only confirm my assertion (**at least for the very first invocation** of `Process.GetProcessById()`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in .NET, although until someone can repro it there's a chance it is just some weirdness on your machine.

Either way, calling LeaveDebugMode() to work around the issue should be harmless.  All it does is disable the privilege, returning the thread to the normal state.  (The documentation doesn't say, but presumably calling LeaveDebugMode() when debug privilege is already disabled simply does nothing; that's how the underlying API behaves.)

Comment: I managed to reproduce it on quite different systems (but both W7-64): an embedded version and a plain W7 Professional. Both install an anti-malware, but not the same: Avira on the W7-embedded and MCafee on W7-professional. Nothing else special is installed. By the way, for backward compatibility reason I have still to use VS2005 (but I don't thing it matters).

Comment: I can't repro it here, but I'm not expert in C# so I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: I am still investigating this issue. The answer is satisfactory for me since I wanted to be sure that the LeaveDebugMode is a reasonable workaround, but I would like to discover the actual source of this weird thing. Maybe some MS hotfix? I'll try my testcase on a completely different machine as soon as possible, I can't believe that such a bug is around and nobody has noticed it. There must be something wrong in my environment. Maybe...

Comment: If it is a bug, it's a subtle one; to notice it you have to be testing that something *doesn't* work - that you do in fact get an error when you attempt to open a process you shouldn't have access to. Programmers mostly test that stuff *does* work.  (I think they call that a negative feature.)  It wouldn't surprise me too much if it had gone unnoticed, particularly if it only occurs under rare circumstances.

Comment: Good point: it is indeed difficult (and not much interesting) to notice that an application has some additional, unexpected permission. I'll let you know if I learn something interesting.

Comment: Some news: I have just repeated the test on a fresh W7-64 Pro. At first it failed (no weird privileges added). Then I logged in as a user with administrative privilege and belonging to "debuggers" group, and the test succeeded. I think that this confirm your idea that the bug has never been reported because its effects are negligible and the set of conditions to satisfy is big (administrator && debugger && (maybe) W7-64 && .NET 2 && probably something more).

Comment: Just a concern: at this point, if I were Microsoft, I would be in trouble if I had to decide to correct the bug. Its effect is to make more things work (i.e. OpenProcess is more likely to succeed, as in my case). So, by correcting it, there may be a compatibility problem with existing binaries that have worked right now "by chance".